# How to solve CORS policy in Angular and jhipster build with docker

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, jhipster

I have a jhipster application with 2 Microservices (moniesta-production and orders) and one gateway. I dockerized all of them together with jhipster docker-compose. So far they all work inside docker. But when I try to make a request with my frontend application (angular)to login for example I get this following error:

```
from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

I saw that when I build my image using this command:

```
./mvnw -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild
```

I am Building wiht production profile. And my application.prod.yml does not contain any cors allow config. but my dev.yml does. So I presume I have to build with this config while developing. I have tried this command:

```
./mvnw -Pdev verify jib:dockerBuild
```

To build with dev profile but did not work it was still production and cors is not allowed. Can someone give me a pointer how to solve this is my guess with the configuration correct? I am new to jhipster and docker.

Comment: As suggested, you could probably fix this using a reverse proxy (either webpack in webpack/proxy.conf.js or the gateway itself but your question does not state how you run the gateway backend or the frontend so it's difficult to say. Anyway, developing inside docker is not very practical because you have a slower build each time you make a change in a backend service.

Comment: I develop normally in my Spring Project but for example my Development in my gateway part is finished and I wanted to build a docker image and start that instead of my Intellj Project just to have it a bit more comfortable. I just could not build the image with the def Profile so it will take those configuration from Jhipster

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using session authentication create a [proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server).

Comment: I have session authentication my token is saved in the session storage of the browser. If that is what you mean

Comment: In that case you'll need to enable CORS on the server, of for development use CORS enabling extension